# Prevent R's newly opened devices to get the focus

Tags: r, graph, focus, x11, xserver

When I open a plot from the `R` console:

- I am happy that the device opens *on top* of the screen so I can see it
- I am unhappy that the device gets the *focus* because I can't type any additional commands then before I navigate back to the console.

How do I get only the first of these two behaviours?
Is there a way to open a new `R` device on top of the screen without loosing the console focus?

---

[Update]: According to [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884372)'s comment, calling `windows(4.5,4.5,restoreConsole=T)` before `plot` does the trick. But this [seems](http://lojze.lugos.si/%7Edarja/software/r/library/grDevices/html/windows.html) to be just a temporary fix for Windows. Any more generic solution? Or `X11`, `Wayland` equivalents?

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) has a plot pane rather than creating new windows, and focus is not lost when plotting. Otherwise, `Alt`+`Tab` might be your only hope.

Comment: Yes, I know about RStudio, but it's a bit too much, and I would loose Vim editing -- which sounds unbearable doesn't it? ;). Let's `Alt+Tab` then untill we find something else.

Comment: I use the following:  `windows(4.5,4.5,restoreConsole=T)` to create a new plot window and return to the console.  Once I'm there (the console), I can run `plot` followed by whatever without moving the focus away. (rgui.exe in Windows).

Comment: This sounds great! Unfortunately, this argument -- even though it looks available for `x11()` -- seems not to work in Linux (`unused argument` error). According to the [doc](http://lojze.lugos.si/~darja/software/r/library/grDevices/html/windows.html), it is just a temporary fix for Windows, but it looks definitely like the feature I would need. Are we getting closer? ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/activate-console-td4077096.html).

```
bringToTop(-1)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this update :) I cannot get this function recognized. Does it come from an exotic package?

Comment: I do not think so it is within grDevices.  Did you try "?bringToTop"  ?

Comment: Unknown (too bad) :\ Would it be a Windows-only-related feature? This is Debian 9 speaking.

Comment: Most likely!  Very unfortunate.  I run into a lot of these problems between mac and windows. :(  Are you running X11? Perhaps you need to update R to 3.4?

Comment: Yup. I'm running X11 with R 3.4.3 (Kite-Eating Tree), I guess it's just an X11 implementation limitation 8)

Comment: ?rgl.bringtotop ?

Comment: Ah, \`knows this one :) I'm not sure it's the same though. But I get `Error in rgl.bringtotop(-1): 'rgl.bringtotop' failed` with a warning `'stay' not implemented`. Is this not supposed to work only with `rgl` windows and not regular `grDevices` ones?